# how to use 2 variables as function name in PHP

Tags: php

I have a code running variable as function name.

```
$id = $_GET["id"];
$thing = 'draw_calendar'.$id;
$$thing = function($month,$year,$per_day_chu){
    //code
}

echo $draw_calendar1(date("m"), date("Y"), $per_day_chu);
```

The above code is running perfectly. But `$id` value is dynamic not a constant value. So I cannot call the function always like `echo $draw_calendar1(date("m"), date("Y"), $per_day_chu);`.

I want to achieve the result something like this `echo $draw_calendar.$id(date("m"), date("Y"), $per_day_chu);`

I know this is a bad option. But I don't have any other option.

Is there any way to get the result.
Whether am doing wrong coding.
Let me finish this. Could anyone help me. Thankyou.

Comment: Why certainly you must use  `$draw_calendar.$id` this code? if the above code work prefect?

Comment: @MahdiParsa : `$id` value is dynamic not a constant value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can concatenate it into a variable like so:

```
$functionName = $draw_calendar . $id;
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
$functionName(date("m"), date("Y"), $per_day_chu);
```

Since your ID is input from a GET parameter, before invoking your function, you might want to validate if it exists because otherwise you'll get an error if it doesn't:

```
if (function_exists($functionName)) {
    $functionName(date("m"), date("Y"), $per_day_chu);
}
```

Comment: what should be `$draw_calendar`

Comment: `$draw_calendar` - this is your string 'draw_calendar'. You can change it on sting `$functionName = 'draw_calendar'. $id;`

Comment: function not exists.

Comment: What if you replace `$functionName` with `$$thing` from your example?

Comment: I tested it, using `$$thing` should work. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYdEw.png) of my test based on your code.